# Xamarin.Forms - Geolocator taking too long

Tags: xamarin.forms, geolocation, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to move the camera to the current user's position.

I can see the blue dot on the map representing my current position.

Now, I have to move the camera to get there (to see it), I want the camera to be automatically moved to that position when the map is displayed.

I'm using the plugin:
Xam.Plugin.Geolocator.

But when I'm trying to move the camera to the current position, the application gets hung. It doesn't crash, it doesn't raise any exception, it's just trying to get the position asynchronously but it's taking too much time.

This is the code I'm using for it:

```
public partial class MenuInitialDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public IGeolocator mLocator { get; set; }

        public MenuInitialDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            mLocator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position currentPosition = mLocator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000), null, true).Result;
            locationMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(currentPosition.Latitude, currentPosition.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `.Result` at the end of the call, you are blocking the UI.